# Ckeditor problem editing form and commenting after migrating site from ddev to live server

Tags: drupal

I just moved my latest d9 site from ddev local to live server and I have several problems...
ckeditor body is blank when I try to edit the node and so is the comment

in console, I get this error

VM1368:87 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.xxxwebdesign.com/photoshop-creations' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.xxxwebdesign.com/themes/xxxwebdesign/styles/css/components/font-awesome.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

seems like my Adaptive theme is still pointing to HTTP instead of HTTPS but there are no settings to fix this......

Comment: Would you not set the server to redirect all http requests to https? Maybe that would fix it?

Comment: i am sorry but it was just caching....now it went away....when I moved from ddev it used non SSL but on live I used HTTPS..so it worked itself out somehow...